# Vertically center view in vertical LinearLayout with 'empty' item

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have `vertical` linear layout with 2 `TextView` children.
I want the children to be vertically centered even if only 1 child actually fill up space.

Here is a test layout :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:text="text text text" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

when `tv2` view is set (as shown), `tv1` will not be vertically centered.
Here is how it looks : (see `tv2` 'fills up space' although it doesn't have any text)

[image]

while what I want is :

[image]

which is actually what happens when the `tv2` is removed from the layout.

BTW, 
I want to avoid using `visibility` attribute, I know I can set to `GONE`

Comment: change your `TextView`s and set their `height` to `0dp` and set their `weight` to `1` and check if it works.

Comment: `0dp` is illegal, it is only legal for `layout_width`, setting the weight to `1.0` isn't working since `tv2` actually takes place (and that's the problem)

Comment: That is backwards, if your orientation is vertical then layout_height="0dp", if it is horizontal then layout_width="0dp" is acceptable. Make sure your appropriately set your weights for each (both TextViews need a layout_height of 0dp and a layout_weight of 1).

Comment: @SagiLow : Using 0dp *IS* allowed for `layout_height` as well as `layout_width`

Comment: Well, you are right, it is legal when setting `weight`, but it isn't working, `tv1` is not on top of the layout

Comment: IT IS on top, and it's not the required behavior (sorry for that, can't edit)

Answer (score 0):

I will delete this as soon as I make sure that you are doing this right and it is still not working for you (based on comments), but I want to double check you are actually setting things right...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="text text text" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This should be your layout. Do you have it setup like this?

**NOTE**

You are explicitly declaring your root LinearLayout height to 60dp. I would not suggest doing so, but if you plan on keeping it that way you could also simply explicitly declare your TextView heights, something like

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" />
```

Please let me know when you have checked and made sure this isn't working.

**EDIT**

This will center your TextViews in the middle of your layout regardless of what is actually in those TextViews:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/light_gray" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="text text text" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks for the assistance, copied and pasted to `layout` and the graphical layout shows again it is not vertically centered.

Comment: @SagiLow it isn't vertically centered? I'm not sure why. The gravity attributes should manage that. Any way you could post a screenshot in your post of what is happening?

Comment: @SagiLow that is centered vertically. There isn't any text in the second TextView, but it still takes up 1/2 the height due to the weight parameter (which is what you asked for). The first TextView will be centered vertically in the top half of the layout, while the second TextView will be centered vertically on the bottom half.

Comment: I didn't ask for  `weight`, i put it there according to the suggestions in this thread, my target is what I posted on the question image, it might not be possible without using `visibility=gone` and that's OK, but according to you it is possible but it's not there yet.

Comment: @SagiLow I think we misunderstood your question based on the way you asked it. That is why we suggested using weights.

Comment: I edited the question, but the required behavior is shown in the second image in the question anyway. thanks!

Comment: @SagiLow I will edit my answer with the working layout when I get a chance.